# PHP - Updating data yearly. -Process advice-

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, csv, process

I have made an employee management system as such, and it calcualtes leave days. Although I am trying to work out how to make the leave days update yearly according to the staffs starting date. 
I think I know how I will do this easily. Except it will involve the software being open on that date.

How would I account for each day, without the software having to be open?

### Heres the process i was thinking:

-Loop through array of staff data and determine if starting date matches current date.

-If it matches then add an ammount of days to their leave days

### I know this is very basic, and it has some flaws. Here are the flaws i am thinking:

-If the page were to be refreshed, or page opened again then it would add x2 of the staff days.

-Also, if the software was not to be opened on this day then the staff would not get the added leave days.

How would I get around this issues? I feel like it should be an easy thing, but I cant think on how to do it properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Run a cron job, that does this on a timed interval ( probably once per day ),  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron  In short cron is a Linux scheduler that you can call a php ( or other ) scripts with at a set time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your php script I'll call it `leavetime.php`

Then if you have c-panel on your server, there is a thing called cron, in there you can select the time to call it.  typically it will be something like this for the command

```
  usr/bin/php -q locationof/leavetime.php
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAbefcWLxrw

As for the actual php code to do this, it's to broad a topic to cover in a single question.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. So do you need to install and implement cron? I have never heard of it before. Would it still add leave days on the dates, even if the software is not turned on? Thanks

Comment: If you have Linux hosting with C-Panel, it's easy, just login to cpanel and it will be in the UI.  If not then windows has something similar I am sure.  It depends on your hosting, and your servers OS on what you need to do exactly.  But essentially it can call a file at a set time, using a simple command.  Then the file will be executed ( if its php ) and the code runs.

Comment: Ok cool. I don't have linux or C-Panel, but I will have a look into it. If I weren't to find a way like this. Do you think I could just hold a datafile which holds how many times they have had leave days added to it, and compare their starting date to the current date. This way the counter will not go over, and will just add the leave dates next time its running..hmm.
Thanks for your help, I will get back to you

Comment: Well you will have to store these leave days somewhere, as well as their starting date, I would use a DB and have a table called employees, and put the stuff in there.  Then you can check in there, it's too general to answer.  For example do they keep unused leave days, do they roll over.  You can tell by the starting day how many years they have worked for the company, so if they roll over and get 5 days per year, an employee that has been 5 years could not have more then 25 leave days,  I would do a total leave days field, and a used leave days field. IE. Don't just remove from the total.

Comment: It's not trivial to build this from scratch, so really depends on your level of coding skills and if you are using any other systems that handle this currently.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense to me. I can see the problem if I just remove it from the total.. Which was what I was going to do haha. Many thanks

Comment: Sure, it's always better to us a non-destructive methodology for these thing.  Essentially store the data in a way that prevents the issue in the first place.